# Pandas and SQL; How to select specific row in database?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I use Pandas to read this SQL using Python (works using SELECT * FROM table):

```
   ID                      Timestamp   
1  AA34234234234234234234  B534  
2  AA34234234234234234234  B864 
3  cv0Qc0PJFDAP5S4T6pn69Y  B435  
4  cv0Qc0PJFDAP5S4T6pn69Y  B978
```

All fields are "TEXT".

Now want to access the last row identical with ID = AA34234234234234234234 and enter this line:

```
status = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = AA34234234234234234234', database).tail(1)
```

I expect to get:

```
   ID                      Timestamp  
2  AA34234234234234234234  B864
```

But I get an error instead:

> (sqlite3.OperationalError) unrecognized token: "AA34234234234234234234"
> [SQL: 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = AA34234234234234234234']
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

I am sure I do a silly syntax mistake but I can't seem to narrow down the issue! The link is not helpful for me at least.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ID column is of string type, you will need to wrap the ID in quotes:

```python
status = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = "4234234234234234234234"', database).tail(1)
```

That is my suspicion of what is happening. I cannot be sure without knowing the table schema.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I used fstrings and placed '' before and end the curlies!

f"SELECT * FROM table  WHERE ID = '{order}'"

Comment: While that does work, I would not recommend it unless using prepared statements. In raw SQL, if someone could change the value of order before it is inserted into that string, you could have your database messed with from SQL injection attacks, such as dropping tables or getting informaton that should be private. Definitely recommend reading about SQL injections and prepared sql statements. Also, glad I was able to help!

Comment: It looks like Pandas read_sql is capable of doing so safely, but in general it is a risky practice. Double check the Pandas docs to ensure you don't expose your database to unnecessary risk. Not as important for small projects while learning, but do keep in mind as you progress :)